# How to set Hudson's classpath

Tags: hudson, websphere, classpath

I am working on a plugin that was written by one of my colleagues which deploys code to a WAS 6.1 server. We are changing to WAS 8 and the plugin now requires classes that were not needed for 6.1. In hudson I see the java.class.path parameter is set to /usr/lib/hudson/hudson.war. Is there a way to add the WebSphere directories containing the jars I need to this classpath. I am currently running the plugin, finding a missing jar, putting it in hudson's WEB-INF\lib directory and repeating all the steps. This is becoming very painful. Any help would be appreciated.